# cypress returning "undefined" argument when using fixture and POM

Tags: javascript, cypress

after fixing some issues with my fixtures I am playing around with cypress scripts using POM but whenever I want my function to type some data I have in my JSON file I get the following message

> cy.type() can only accept a string or number. You passed in: undefined

Here is my code, I made sure to follow correct instructions on how to use the fixtures

```html
import loginPage from '../POM/pomtest.js'

const credentials = require('../../fixtures/loginTestCases.json')

/// <reference types= "cypress" />
describe("test suite", function(){
    let credentials;

    before(() => {
        cy.fixture('loginFixture').then((logindata) =>{
            credentials = logindata;
            return credentials
        });
    })

    beforeEach(() =>{
        loginPage.visit();
        cy.wrap(credentials).as('credentials')
    })

    it('incorrect username', function (){
        loginPage.clickLoginBtn()
        loginPage.typeUsername(this.credentials.usernameIncorrecto);
        loginPage.typePassword(this.credentials.passwordCorrecto);
        loginPage.clickLoginBtn();
        loginPage.elements.myNotes().should('have.text', this.credentials.loginFallido);
    })

    it('incorrect password', function (){
        loginPage.clickLoginBtn()
        loginPage.typeUsername(this.credentials.usernameCorrecto);
        loginPage.typePassword(this.credentials.passwordIncorrecto)
        loginPage.clickLoginBtn()
        loginPage.elements.myNotes().should('have.text', this.credentials.loginFallido)
    })

    it('Valid Login', function (){
        loginPage.clickLoginBtn()
        loginPage.typeUsername(this.credentials.usernameCorrecto);
        loginPage.typePassword(this.credentials.passwordCorrecto)
        loginPage.clickLoginBtn()
        loginPage.elements.myNotes().should('have.text', this.credentials.loginCorrecto)
    })
})
```

And here is my POM file

```html
class loginPage{
    elements = {
        usernameInput: () => cy.xpath("//input[@placeholder='Username']"),
        passwordInput: () => cy.xpath("//input[@name='login.password']"),
        loginBtn: () => cy.get('button').contains('Login'),
        errorMsg: () => cy.get('#login-error-message'),
        myNotes: () => cy.get('H2')
    }

    typeUsername(username){
        this.elements.usernameInput().type(username);
    }

    typePassword(password){
        this.elements.passwordInput().type(password);
    }

    clickLoginBtn(){
        this.elements.loginBtn().click();
    }

    visit(){
        cy.visit("http://testapp.galenframework.com/")
    }

    fillemail(value){
        let field = cy.xpath("//input[@placeholder='Username']")
        field.clear()
        field.type(value)
    }

    fillpassword(value){
        let field = cy.xpath("//input[@name='login.password']")
        field.clear()
        field.type(value)
    }
}
//export default loginPage
module.exports = new loginPage();
```

I am getting errors when trying to type what's on my JSON file

```html
[
  {
  "usernameIncorrecto": "incorrecto@gmail.com",
  "passwordIncorrecto": "incorrecta",
  "usernameCorrecto": "testuser@example.com",
  "passwordCorrecto": "test123",
  "loginFallido": "The username or password are incorrect",
  "loginCorrecto": "My Notes"
}
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that your `credentials` variable is an array, but you are trying to directly access properties the variable does not have. (Additionally, the properties you call don't exist on the objects even if they were referenced correctly. You should either switch to finding the data by an index, or using a name property on the object.

```js
// accessing data via an index
    it('incorrect username', function (){
        loginPage.clickLoginBtn()
        loginPage.typeUsername(this.credentials[0]. usernameIncorrecto);
        loginPage.typePassword(this.credentials[0]. passwordIncorrecto);
        loginPage.clickLoginBtn();
        loginPage.elements.myNotes().should('have.text', this.credentials[0]. loginFallido);
    })
```

Notice in the above how I've used `this.credentials[0]` to access the first object in your JSON. Using this method, you could also declare a variable at the beginning of the `it` block to simplify this.

```js
it('incorrect username', function() {
  const creds = this.credentials[0];
  ...
  loginPage.typeUsername(creds.usernameIncorrecto);
  ...
})
```

Comment: Thanks! I made it that way using another approach but what I was looking for with this was to iterate over the JSON so save time on creating repeating scripts

Comment: You could still do that if it was an array, and just iterate through your credentials array, like`this.credentials.forEach((creds) => {})`.

Comment: Just noticed i posted the incorrect JSON file, thanks for letting me know. Would that change your answer?

Comment: As it is, with the object being in an array, I wouldn't change my answer, you'd just have to update the actual properties being called _once you have accessed the object_. I'll update my answer to reflect those properties.